# Logic app Outlook subject filter not working

Tags: filter, outlook, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that Initializes a Variable (Timestamp + a phrase), sends an email with that as the subject line, then polls the destination mailbox (O365 mailbox) looking for that exact Subject line, using the get emails (v3) function.

And yet, when the get email function runs, it doesn't retrieve anything, showing only a blank output which is breaking other parts of the Logic App:

[image]

The String looks like this: '2023-12-08T03:57:22.3748840Z Round Robin Test Email'

I've tried all sorts of quotation marks, string(variables('var1')), I've tried concatting the string with a search parameter, tried using the customer search query - and nothing works.

Currently, I've reverted back to just calling the Variable:

[image]

It's driving me loony and up the wall. Either I've missed something obvious or there's a bug or something else?

Comment: If you are taking current time and sending an email amending that time as Subject line then logic app takes few seconds to send the email to the outlook. So if you try to fetch that email in the same workflow then it will give you blank result because at that moment, subjected email might not been sent to the inbox.

Comment: You can get the email using the phrase like "Round Robin" as the subject filter

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin - Unfortunately no, we can't just use Round Robin, we need the timestamp as each email is unique (there are reasons for this) The get-email runs in an until loop for ~1 minute until it gets it - which is never does, I even added a delay in the workflow - it doesn't match.

Comment: I have added a delay of 20sec before the Get emails action and I am able to fetch the email details, check [this](https://i.imgur.com/sozXw9E.png) and [this](https://i.imgur.com/yvA6mHv.png)

Comment: You could use another app and have the new email trigger as the trigger.

Comment: @skin, no because there's no way to go back in time and get the timestamp from the previous run.

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin - the Get Email though sits inside an until - so it should keep retrying for up to a minute until it gets the message - but it doesn't.

Comment: @TheDemonLord can you share the screenshot of your until loop? Even I was getting blank earlier but now I am getting data after adding delay of 20sec. what's the until condition in your case?

Comment: @TheDemonLord I believe until loop will execute based on the loop condition.

Comment: Yes there is, you just gotta do the work.

Comment: @TheDemonLord If you want to use Until loop only and don't want to add Delay in your workflow then you can increase the count of the Until loop to 2. By doing so you will get the data in the second call

Answer (score 0):

> when the get email function runs, it doesn't retrieve anything, showing only a blank output which is breaking other parts of the Logic App

You have added both the Send Email and Get Emails actions in one workflow and you are passing the current time in the Email subject. By the time Get emails action polls the Inbox for the exact subject line, that email might not reach the Inbox at that moment, as logic app takes few seconds to send email to our Outlook. So You might consider adding delay in your workflow post Send Email (V2) action.

Though you are using Get Emails (V3) action inside Until loop but the execution of the loop depends on the loop condition.

Here I am using Delay in the workflow to get the email details. You can modify the count according to your requirement.

[image]

I am able to get the details as shown below-

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you still want to use Until loop, then you need to modify the loop condition by keeping few seconds of execution time.